# ffmpeg - конвертация определенной аудиодорожки в контейнере mkv

Tags: ffmpeg

Есть видеофайл в формате (контейнере) mkv. В нём несоколько звуковых дорожек. Нужно сконвертировать только определенную из них, остальное оставив "как есть".
Прошу помощи с параметрами ffmpeg для данного случая.

Более конкретно в качестве примера.
MKV-файл содержит (по порядку идентификатора):

```
0: Видео - MPEG-4p10/AVC/H.264
1: Аудио - MP3
2: Субтитры - SubStationAlpha
3: Аудио - TrueHD (6 channels)
```

Нужно переконвертировать аудиодорожку с ID = 3 из `TrueHD` в `AC3` не трогая дорожку, которая MP3, т.е. всё остальное перенести "как есть".
Информацию как просто переконвертировать звук я в интернете нашел, а вот как это сделать только для определенной дорожки нет.
Не могу понять, как использовать параметр `-map` для такого случая, если это возможно.
Или одной операцией не получиться и нужно сначала извлекать, конвертировать и заменять(удалять, вставлять) полученную дорожку?

Comment: Все дорожки кроме нужной прогоняешь через  кодек copy. Не трогать не получится

Comment: Под "не трогать" я имел ввиду именно не конвертировать. Понятно, что результирующий файл будет другой. Но, в том то и дело, что не получается: не могу добиться конвертации одного стрима: `Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 1, only the last option '-c:a ac3' will be used.
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 3, only the last option '-c:a ac3' will be used.`

Comment: Мне тоже нужно было перекодировать аудиодорожку в фильме 4k, потому что самсунги проебали поддержку dts, а то что описано здесь неприменимо без тех знаний, которые понадобились для написания оного.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Стоило ли преобразовывать в комментарий сообщение, содержащее нелитературные речевые обороты?

Answer (score 3):

Подсказали на другом ресурсе.
Ответ:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -c:v:0 copy -c:a:0 copy -c:s:0 copy -c:a:1 ac3 output.mkv`